# Mensaje raro en compilación de mi app en Android Studio

Tags: compilacion

Alguien me puede ayudar? ¿Porqué me sale este mensaje cuando le doy run a mi app? antes no me salía pero ahora me sale en cualquier proyecto o app que la haga correr. He revisado todo el código y no hay ningún error ni warning ni nada.
[image: Mensaje raro en compilación]

Comment: Prueba la opción `Clean Project` y luego `Rebuild Project` (ambas están en la opción `Build` del menú superior de Android Studio) y luego intenta de nuevo. Considera usar siempre `Debug` para depurar tus proyectos.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, disculpa, no me sale esas opciones en mi menú superior de Android Studio. Creo q este mensaje apareció desde que lo actualize mi Flutter